# I cannot export the test run on Jenkins with a file with xml extension

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Ls3.png)
I did a test run with newman on jenkins. It ran the tests and submitted the report no problem. but when I want to export and save to newman folder it gives this error.
How can I solve this problem?

I downloaded reporter, junit to my computer and created newman folder but the problem is not solved.

Comment: `--reporters` seems to be a flag or command argument that needs to be passed to `newman` rather than used as a command.

Comment: --reporters cli,junit --reporter-junit-export "newman/otelReservation.xml" When I wrote this command in a single line, the problem was solved.